# How to fix my code after a git revert?

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on a local git repo that was cloned from a remote repo. I made some changes, committed locally, and pushed my code to the remote repo.

A bug was found in my code so a team member reverted my commit. So now the remote repo is ahead of me by 1 commit (the revert commit).

Current state: I have no local modifications, and the remote is ahead of me by the revert commit (and lets say 1 unrelated commit, if thats relevant).

What do I need to do to get in sync with the remote, but still have my buggy code around to fix?

Saw a lot of stuff on how to revert, but not what to do after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `git pull` to update your branch to the same state as your remote branch.

Then, run `git cherry-pick --no-commit <commit>`, where `<commit>` is your broken commit.

This will move all of the changes from `<commit>` back onto your branch, without committing them.

Comment: Aha `cherry-pick`. Did not know about that.

Comment: @dan08 You can also `git revert --no-commit <commit>`, where <commit> is the one your team member made to revert your changes